# Send keystroke over ssh C#

Tags: c#, ssh

I have a server that is accessed through an SSH session. When I log in, it immediately launches an application within the console window that only responds to keystrokes. Just to be clear, I'm running Renci SSH to log in and run commands, but when the application asks me to make a selection by entering a character, sending a command with that character as the command doesn't work. For example, the first window in the application is a menu; selecting option "1" requires that I type "1" and then hit the enter key, but when I send "1" as a command, it gives me an error saying the command doesn't exist.

How can I send a keystroke over ssh using a C# ssh library (preferably renci ssh.net)? To add a hiccup to this, I can't install any additional software to this server and I have no idea whether or not software I could use exists on the server.